# Program fails in Python 2.7.8 but runs in Python 3.4.1

Tags: python

I've ran this code using Python 3.4.1 and it works, but if I use Python 2.7.8 it fails, why?

```
i=1
while i<10:
    for x in(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9):
        print (i*x,'\t',end='')
        if x==9:   
            print('\n')
            i=i+1
```

Comment: Your question title is quite different from the question body - please fix it. Also, adding the error message you get would be tremendously helpful

Comment: There are so many places on the internet that will tell you the differences between Python 2.x and Python 3.x (https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html for a start). Have a read through those. If you're just starting with Python, start with Python 3 and leave Python 2 out for the moment.

Comment: Your question *title* is off topic here; we cannot help you with a 'best' choice here. The title and question body are entirely unrelated though, but your question body is lacking in detail to be answered without guessing. **How** does the code fail in Python 2? What did you instead expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, `print` is a function in Python 3 but not Python 2. In Python 2, you need to remove `()` and `end`.  As an alternative, you can add `from __future__ import print_function` into your code in Python 2 to use `print` as in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

Amongst the breaking changes between Python versions 2.x and 3.x is that [`print` is a **function**](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) - in 2.x it was a **statement**. You have two options, either use:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the top of your script to use the new function in 2.x, or have a separate 2.x version with the old syntax:

```
print '{0}\t'.format(i * x), # note trailing comma to suppress newline
```

The former is much easier, in my opinion.

Note that the default `sep` equivalent for the 2.x `print` statement is a single space, so the naïve version

```
print i * x, '\t',
```

would include an extra space before the tab. Also, note that your 3.x version can be slightly simpler:

```
print(i * x, end='\t')
```