# Python 3 to 2 equivalent code

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is from Ken Lambert's book, based on Python 3.

```
print('The median is', end=" ")
```

What is the equivalent in Python 2? I think it's the 'end=' that's causing the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program fails in Python 2.7.8 but runs in Python 3.4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641292/program-fails-in-python-2-7-8-but-runs-in-python-3-4-1)

Answer (score 2):

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

will do it. That'll disable the [`print` *statement*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) and give you the [`print()` *function*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) instead.

Or, use the comma after the `print` statement:

```
print 'The median is',
```

Quoting from the `print` statement documentation:

> A `'\n'` character is written at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma.

Because a `print` with a comma leaves the output not at the start of a line, causing `print` to add a space when next printing an object.

Demo:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> if True:
...     print 'The median is',
...     print 42.81
... 
The median is 42.81
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print
<built-in function print>
>>> if True:
...     print('The median is', end=' ')
...     print(42.81)
... 
The median is 42.81
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

```
print 'The median is',
```

or:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print('The median is', end=" ")
```